# Visual Studio Auto Tidy?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have a question about how to enable automatic code tidying property in Visual Studio. I have no idea whether I have used the word correctly or not. What I'm doing is that I'm using Visual Studio in my personal laptop and also on a separate computer. In the laptop when I'm working on writing C++ code when I press "Enter" all the code automatically rearranges so that it looks more elegant and tidy. I did not enable it on purpose; I just like it and I would like to do the same thing on another computer as well. Is there anyone out there who knows how to do this stuff? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're referring to "code formatting" support. Each language (C#, C++, VB, etc.) have their own implementation of this. To trigger it directly, you can find the command in the menus by going to Edit -> Advanced -> Format Document (or Format Selection). There are also keyboard shortcuts that do it, I use CTRL-E, D all the time, but that may be language specific so you should experiment some.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can either Format Selection by using CTRL+K, CTRL+F and you can format the whole document by pressing CTRL+E, D.

You can also do this by going to Edit -> Advanced -> Format Document/Format Selection

For more options about formatting you can go to Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C++ -> Formatting